# how to save data on react if page get reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, instagram, url-routing

I am new to react, I try to make clone of Instagram, the problem I face was in original Instagram **when user enter his login details and click on login button, the page get reload** and it move us to home page of Instagram and we see post so how I can achieve this functionality.
**The main problem is how to store the details after page get reload?**
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data using `localStorage` inside browser.

For example

```
window.localStorage.user = 1234;
```

Here is complete documentation about `localStorage`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage